# Switching the Source of a QDeclarativeView

Tags: c++, qt, view, swap

First question here, so bear with me.

I have been trying to create a view on a QMainWindow using a QDeclarativeView as the canvas, but whenever I try to switch the source of the QDeclarativeView my program segfaults and I frankly have no idea why, or how to fix it.

Here is my swapView() function.

```
void MainWindow::swapView(int view)
{
 switch (view)
 {
    case 0:
        cout << "Switching to Slideshow..." << endl;
        this->setSource("Slideshow.qml");
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "Switching to Main Canvas..." << endl;
        this->setSource("Test.qml");
        cout << "Successfully switched to Main Canvas!" << endl;
        break;
 }
}
```

Here is the setSource() method that it is calling:

```
void MainWindow::setSource(QString fileName)
{
    this->ui->declarativeView->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Test.qml"));
}
```

I tried replacing the code above with the code below, and it gets rid of the segfault, but each window opens in a separate window instead of just replacing the view on the QDeclarativeView.

```
void MainWindow::setSource(QString fileName)
{
    QDeclarativeView *view = new QDeclarativeView;
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
    ui->declarativeView = view;
    ui->declarativeView->show();
}
```

If anyone has any input on what I'm doing wrong (I'm sure it's something stupid), please let me know...

Thanks.

Comment: Try making a temporary test variable `QUrl temp = QUrl::fromLocalFile("Test.qml");`, and see if it is valid `temp.isValid()` - perhaps that is one of the problems? The code you posted seems fine unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I did as you suggested with the 2nd version of the code, and it still created a completely new window each time as it did previously, and it printed that the QUrl provided was valid.

With the first version of the code, it does the same thing as it did originally with a valid QUrl. Loads the first view fine, but then segfaults when I try to load the 2nd

Comment: I tried this code,     void switchView() {
        if( view->source() == QUrl("qrc:/Rect.qml")) {
           view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
       } else {
           view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Rect.qml"));
       }
    }, it works fine, what is source of segfault ?

Comment: I honestly am not sure what the source of the seg fault is, but it only happens when I change the QML source file of the QDeclarativeView that is the child of my QMainWindow. I've tried calling the `setSource()` function from everywhere in my code, and in every way I can think of but it SegFaults each and every time unless I create an entirely new view that is also in a new window (which is not what I want).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this crash is caused by destruction of an C++ object managed by the old document inside this object method. In my case I have MuseArea which triggers a slot in my C++ code which switches source document. **Something like this crashes**:

QML code:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: cppObject.action()
}
```

C++ code

```
QDeclarativeView * viewInstance();

class CppObject: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
     void action() { viewInstance()->setSource("another.qml") }
};
```

The way to fix it is to use queued connection somewhere between code called by QML event and setSource call. **The following code works well**:

QML code:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: cppObject.actionNeeded()
}
```

C++ code

```
QDeclarativeView * viewInstance();

class CppObject: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit CppObject(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
     {
         connect(
             this,SIGNAL(actionNeeded()),
             this,SLOT(action()),
             Qt::QueuedConnection
         );
     }
public slots:
     void action() { viewInstance()->setSource("another.qml") }
signals:
     void actionNeeded();
};
```